# Correct way to create a Desktop Entry file of Directory type?

Tags: xfce

What elements should I define in a Desktop Entry file of Directory type for xfce? Although it can be created using thunar file manager by right clicking on the folder, so what I want to know is that if its possible to create one manually.

*I wish XFCE was well documented as other DEs*

Answer (score 2):

This is what I found. This will look and behave in nautilus/nemo like a normal folder instead of a symlink. Being a link it can have any name or image while being de facto a GUI folder. It can also link to a distant folder. And contrary to some solutions here, it will not open a new window if opened from nemo.

For `/mnt/HDD/Videos/`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Videos
Icon=folder-video.png
Type=Link
URL=file:///mnt/HDD/Videos/
```

For `sftp://192.168.1.7/mnt/HDD/Videos/`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Videos
Icon=folder-video.png
Type=Link
URL=sftp://192.168.1.7/mnt/HDD/Videos/
```

Comment: Should be `URL=file:///mnt/HDD/Videos/`, not `URL=/mnt/HDD/Videos/`

Comment: I was able to do the same thing by right clicking on xfce4 desktop, and create a URL link with `file:///mnt/HDD/Videos`

Comment: This is not directory type. It says `Type=Link`. Directory type is described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/817-5310/6mkpbn3ti/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You will find detailed information on desktop entry files [here](http://linuxcritic.wordpress.com/2010/04/07/anatomy-of-a-desktop-file/).

I'm unable to find XFCE's desktop entry specifications, but [in Gnome desktop entry specifications](http://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/), the desktop entry for a directory must be ending with `.directory`, and not `.desktop`.

Comment: Actually that link is the origin of my question. I tried setting type to Directory but xfce perceives it as an invalid .desktop file and it does not recognize .directory.

Answer (score 1):

Create a symlink, for example:

```
ln -s /home/pi/resources /home/pi/Desktop/Course\ Resources
```

The first part is the folder you want to link and the second part is the link on the desktop.

Comment: And what does the third argument (`Resources`) mean?

Comment: @mook765 That's part of the second argument; it's just a folder name with a space in it, but bash needs paths with spaces to be escaped with a backslash.

Answer (score 1):

To create an entry in menu you can use the command,

```
exo-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/.local/share/applications
```

for creating a directory shortcut, you can provide command as

```
thunar /path/to/dir/
```

`thunar` can be replaced with any other file manager commands like `nautilus`

In my case, I used this command to create a shortcut for an AppImage downloaded.

Reference: [howto:customize-menu | Xfce Wiki](https://wiki.xfce.org/howto/customize-menu)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/817-3851/menustructure-tbl-15/index.html) correctly, `Type=Directory` does not create a launcher, but provides metadata for a menu.

Although I couldn't find any official documentation how to create a directory launcher, this worked for me:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=foobar
Exec=xdg-open /path/to/foobar
Icon=folder
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```